# Zurb Foundation + Jade + Express Uncaught Type Error has no method 'foundation'

Tags: node.js, express, zurb-foundation

I am using Express and Jade with Zurb's Foundation.

This is the first time I've encountered this problem and I'm stuck.

I keep getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation'

I wager that I'm throwing this off a bit by using Jade but if I am, I'm lost. Heres the meat of the code:

```
!!! 5
//if lt IE 7
    html.no-js.ie6.oldie(lang='en')
//if IE 7
    html.no-js.ie7.oldie(lang='en')
//if IE 8
    html.no-js.ie8.oldie(lang='en')
//[if gt IE 8]><!
html.no-js(lang='en')
  //<![end if]
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge,chrome=1')
    title=title
    meta(name="description", content=description)
    meta(name="author", content=author)
    meta(name="viewport", content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')

    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/foundation.min.css")

    script(src="/javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js")
    script(src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js")
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')

  body 
    .row
      block content

    // Foundation Footer tools 
    script.
     document.write('<script src=' +
      ('__proto__' in {} ? 'javascripts/vendor/zepto' : 'javascripts/vendor/jquery') +
      '.js><\\/script>')


    script(defer, src='/javascripts/foundation.min.js')
    script.
      $(document).foundation();

    block scripts
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery instance is not properly loaded. The URL is not properly crafted as you can see, you are missing the **HTTP** prefix.

```
script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')
```

The Foundation Footer tools also try to load jQuery, but it seems to failed because your are using a relative path. You should append a '**/**' in front of the javascripts URL as such:

```
script.
     document.write('<script src=' +
      ('__proto__' in {} ? '/javascripts/vendor/zepto' : '/javascripts/vendor/jquery') +
      '.js><\\/script>')
```

Also I suggest moving this statement near the Head. Loading properly jQuery will get you rid of the error.

Regards

Comment: That comment about the URL is incorrect. That form is the RECOMMENDED URL format for CDN's as the browser will automatically match the protocol to HTTP or HTTPS as needed and so avoid pointless browser warnings about mixed content.